Warning: Detected unsettled top-level await
The following code results in error Warning: Detected unsettled top-level await. I don't understand why all of a sudden this block is throwing error when it was working just an hour ago. Didn't make any changes to my dev environment.
I think that the dynamic import promise or startTunnel promise is unsettled that's why this error is thrown, but what I don't understand why an hour later this code is throwing error when it was working perfectly fine before.
I know that the message says Warning, but the process exits right after printing this warning.
let appUrl: string | undefined = isProd
  ? process.env.APP_URL
  : await (async () => {
      const { default: startTunnel } = await import("./lib/startTunnel.js");
      const url = await startTunnel(PORT);
      return url;
    })();

Environment:

nodejs v22.4.1
typescript v5.5.4

// tsconfig.json

// https://www.totaltypescript.com/tsconfig-cheat-sheet
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Base Options: */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "target": "es2022",
    "allowJs": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleDetection": "force",
    "isolatedModules": true,

    /* Strictness */
    "strict": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,

    /* If transpiling with TypeScript: */
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,

    /* If your code doesn't run in the DOM: */
    "lib": ["es2022"]
  }
}

startTunnel.ts
import { startTunnel } from "untun";


export default async (port: number) => {
  try {
    const tunnel = await startTunnel({ port });

    if (!tunnel) throw new Error("unable to start tunnel");

    const tunnelUrl = await tunnel.getURL();

    return tunnelUrl;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error((error as Error).message);
  }
};


Edit: added screenshot


It's not an error. It's a warning.

"I understand that the promise is unsettled" - which promise exactly doesn't settle in your code and why?

Is there something wrong with this code, because now I run this code and its working again

I've added the screenshot. After this message, the process exited

Well did you expect the process to exit (and do you understand why it does that)? Please show us what startTunnel(PORT) does.

Added the code for startTunnel, no I didn't expect it to crash because I'm handling Error  inside catch block

Well it doesn't crash (in which case you would have gotten an exception with a stack trace). It just stops normally after there's nothing left to do; there's no attached event handlers waiting for anything. However it does warn you that this is probably not what you intended to happen, as there are still unresolved top-level-awaited promises left hanging. This appears to be a bug in that untun library, you should report it.

Yes, you're right. Have already mentioned it in the answer.

Ok after spending some time with this I found that the error was occuring because:

startTunnel function from untun doesn't throw any errors. That's why there weren't any console logs.
There aren't any logs but my guess is that I was being rate limited because of regenerating tunnels in a short span.

